# how to install google chrome from terminal

Tags: language-support

I tried to do this in the terminal `sudo apt-get install google chrome`  but the package does not exist please help

Comment: For the Ubuntu repository version of chrome install 'chromium-browser'. This is not exactly the same browser you will get by installing the deb published by the chrome site. For reasons I will not defend I prefer the version released through the chrome website.

Comment: As commented above, Google Chrome is NOT in the repositories but Chromium is and you can use that. If you really want Chrome you can conveniently install the DEB file provided by Google or, in terminal, add the Google Chrome's repository, *then* install the desired version, **exactly as mentioned in the answer below that, BTW, you should've accepted already**. That's how a Q&A site works.

Answer (score 14):

I think you didn't add the google-chrome repository to Ubuntu.
open your terminal and then type:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

then after that to add the repository, type this :

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
```

after that update your system,type this in terminal :

```
sudo apt update
```

last, to install google chrome, type this :

```
sudo apt install google-chrome-**<version>**
```

where version is **beta** or **stable** or **release**

for example :

```
sudo apt install google-chrome-stable
```

I prefer to use the stable version.

Comment: Finally, the answer I was looking for too. Most command line answers wanted me to edit the sources file myself to add the repo. I just wanted a simple command line way to do it. Thanks for this.

Comment: you're welcoma @colorful-shirts